PostGIS min and max distance between bounding boxes
I've been exploring the capabilities of PostGIS get the minimum and maximum distances between bounding boxes.
--returns distance between centroids
select ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING Z(0 0 0, 1 1 1)') <<->> ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING Z(2 0 0, 3 1 1)'); 

Documentation references the <<#>> operator (is it for this purpose?), despite it being removed (Task #3133, Commit #13607) from PostGIS 9 years ago!
--doesn't work
select ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING Z(0 0 0, 1 1 1)') <<#>> ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING Z(2 0 0, 3 1 1)'); 

I'm aware of the ST_3DDistance and ST_3DMaxDistance functions, but my understanding is that they don't utilize spatial indexes, which could impact performance for large datasets. Also this functions is not for bounding boxes. Given this limitation, I'm reaching out to inquire about alternative methods or operators available in PostGIS for achieving this task while still benefiting from spatial indexing.

In the PostGIS context of pairwise distance between complex geometric objects there really is nothing to be gained by indexation, except for the specific cases of proximity searches (distance relationships) and (K)NN lookups. The former of those is implemented via ST_3DDWithin, the latter would require a (working) implementation of an n-D index driven operator like <<#>> - both, however, do not care about a maximum distance. Please specify what you are trying to achieve here.

PostgreSQL indexes are tied to operators in specific operator classes:

PostgreSQL indexes can be used to optimize queries that contain one or more WHERE or JOIN clauses of the form

indexed-column indexable-operator comparison-value


Functions that use an index do so only because they wrap an operator:

If they wrap only the operator, the db just rewrites the whole thing to strip the wrapper and inlines the operation, which enables the index use.
If they wrap the operator and some other function, it's again stripped and rewritten with the operations inlined, then planner/optimizer uses the operator first to pre-filter the rows using the index so that the (more expensive) function has to only re-check that subset of rows.

It's a convenience thing: technically, there's no difference between PostgreSQL rewriting your queries to do that and you splitting your conditions to always have one that'll result in index-backed pre-filtering. You could choose to do that for verbosity (or to show off) and in this case you might also want to do that to emulate the missing index support for these functions.


<<#>> operator (is it for this purpose?), despite it being removed

It's no longer there: you can list all operators with \do+ meta-command in psql client or ask about that specific one with \do+ <<#>> - it's gone. It does look like you could've used it in this manner:
select t1.id
      ,ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING Z(0 0 0, 1 1 1)')<<#>>t1.geom 
       as bbox_nd_dist
from t1
order by bbox_nd_dist
limit 5;

To get the top 5 closest n-d geometries by bbox distance to your n-d location constant, similar to how you can still do a similar thing using <<->>. Demo at db<>fiddle:
select t1.id
      ,ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING Z(0 0 0, 1 1 1)')<<->>t1.geom 
       as bbox_nd_dist
from t1
order by bbox_nd_dist
limit 5;

And you let your ST_3DDistance() and ST_3DMaxDistance() work off of that:
prepare closest_5_by_bbox_centroid_dist_with_3d_minmax as
select t1.id
      ,('LINESTRING Z(0 0 0, 1 1 1)')<<->>t1.geom as bbox_nd_dist
      ,ST_3DDistance('LINESTRING Z(0 0 0, 1 1 1)',t1.geom )
      ,ST_3DMaxDistance('LINESTRING Z(0 0 0, 1 1 1)',t1.geom )
      ,ST_AsText(t1.geom)
from t1
order by bbox_nd_dist
limit 5;

explain analyze verbose execute closest_5_by_bbox_centroid_dist_with_3d_minmax;

execute closest_5_by_bbox_centroid_dist_with_3d_minmax;




QUERY PLAN




Limit  (cost=0.28..10.22 rows=5 width=60) (actual time=0.838..1.540 rows=5 loops=1)


  Output: id, (('010200008002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000F03F000000000000F03F000000000000F03F'::geometry <<->> geom)), (st_3ddistance('010200008002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000F03F000000000000F03F000000000000F03F'::geometry, geom)), (st_3dmaxdistance('010200008002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000F03F000000000000F03F000000000000F03F'::geometry, geom)), (st_astext(geom))


  ->  Index Scan using t1_geom_idx on public.t1  (cost=0.28..39788.28 rows=20000 width=60) (actual time=0.837..1.538 rows=5 loops=1)


        Output: id, ('010200008002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000F03F000000000000F03F000000000000F03F'::geometry <<->> geom), st_3ddistance('010200008002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000F03F000000000000F03F000000000000F03F'::geometry, geom), st_3dmaxdistance('010200008002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000F03F000000000000F03F000000000000F03F'::geometry, geom), st_astext(geom)


        Order By: (t1.geom <<->> '010200008002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000F03F000000000000F03F000000000000F03F'::geometry)


Planning Time: 0.062 ms


Execution Time: 1.585 ms






id
bbox_nd_dist
st_3ddistance
st_3dmaxdistance
st_astext




5154
1.2265554060761976
1.2265554060761976
41.907807214957785
LINESTRING Z (1.820253724657039 0.088855224255779 1.045941950996254,12.305652619659247 9.346125606512068 38.95491182530954)


17753
1.3254448327186006
1.3254448327186006
53.810515990862335
LINESTRING Z (6.912558610659936 34.38044687771512 40.81388289719138,0.05845819248389 0.252426729772282 1.770059493670884)


1
1.632993161855452
1.632993161855452
3.3166247903554
LINESTRING Z (2 0 0,3 1 1)


14057
2.3109574685626173
2.3109574685626173
71.03687069238995
LINESTRING Z (45.39431761086846 44.30182475974057 31.983452743069584,0.445817205113086 1.335705161303014 3.218266867631392)


7838
2.388503176921192
2.388503176921192
66.90272437780929
LINESTRING Z (43.76643517023001 29.426320330776235 41.16509873003727,2.877614942878026 1.367999006777732 2.429715455415649)



